# Javascript CSOM SP.List get_onQuickLaunch

Tags: 2010, javascript, client-object-model

I am trying to get the onQuickLaunch flag from a SP.List using javascript. I am able to get other list attributes, however when I try to execute

```
list.get_onQuickLaunch();
```

I get an error

```
Uncaught Error: The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.
```

Below is my code, I started traversing down to the quickLaunch object hoping it would help me, but it doesn't look like it has.

```
ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
web = ctx.get_web();
nav = web.get_navigation();
ql = nav.get_quickLaunch();
list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Hey');

ctx.load(web);
ctx.load(nav);
ctx.load(ql);
ctx.load(list);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
  console.log('done'); 
  console.log(list.get_onQuickLaunch());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs due to  [OnQuickLaunch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list.onquicklaunch.aspx) property is not initialized for [SPList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.aspx) object on the client side.

> It means that not all properties are retrieved for List by default.

In order to retrieve additional properties it should be specified explicitly.
So, for the current example the line:

```
ctx.load(list);
```

should be changed to this one:

```
ctx.load(list,"OnQuickLaunch");
```

After that property `OnQuickLaunch` could be retrieved using `get_onQuickLaunch()` function